# Selenium and Azure Web App

Tags: azure, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, azure-webjobs

I have an app using Selenium's ChromeDriver to click and retrieve a file from a website. I have decided to publish it as an Azure Job, would I still be able to run parts of the code that interface the ChromeDriver?

Also, I prefer not to use PhantomJS as sometimes it throws an error that the element is unclickable.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Might not be possible on Azure App Service.

From https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

> #### Unsupported Frameworks
>
> [...]
>
> PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.

If you can convince Selenium to not bind to a socket on 127.0.0.1 and if you're not using stuff that hooks into GDI+ then it MAY work, it's a long shot though.

Try Cloud Services with a Worker Role instead or a VM (IaaS).
I deployed a few functional tests (Phantom) in a Webrole (Cloud Services) and everything went without a hitch. In my particular case i'm calling those tests from the build server over REST.